# How to calculate a point out of an angle and a distance?

Tags: java, math

I searched and implemented things from this forum, it doesn't come out right.
What I'm trying to achieve is to calculate a `spawnPoint` for player bullets relative to his `position` and `rotation`.

The `spawnPoint` should be and his `X + his width` (the player is set to point to the right by default) and `y + height/2` (to spawn from his center on the `Y` axis).

This is what I got from this forum:

```
this.bulletSpawn.x = (float)(this.position.x + this.width/2 + this.width * Math.cos(rotation));
this.bulletSpawn.y = (float)(this.position.y + this.height/2 + this.height/2 * Math.sin(rotation));
```

The `rotation` is in Radians. The `this` is the `Player` class.

Images showing what I expect to happen:

- [Original Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGpIj.jpg)
- [Expected Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upb00.jpg)

The red dot is the `spawnPoint` I'm trying to calculate knowing the player `position` and `rotation`.
The player Sprite is what rotates, and it rotates related to his center x and y, which is done with a lib, i do not have these variables. The entire arrow would be the player , the arrow direction is where the player is pointing at, and the red dot would be the bulletSpawn point (or the expected one)

Using the code I posted, the bullets seem to be spawning from somewhere else. Even at the beggining they have an offset and when I rotate the player the `spawnPoint` seems to be relative to a different origin than what I'm expecting.

This is the bullet position code:

```
position.x = holder.bulletSpawn.x - (float)(this.width/2 * holder.rotation);
position.y = holder.bulletSpawn.y - (float)(this.height/2 * holder.rotation);
```

This is inside the `Bullet` class. The `position` variable is a `Vector2` of `bullet`, and `holder` is the player instance. This code is merely to give an offset for the bullet to spawn at the center of its own size

I added some fixes related to the comments, but the bullets still have a tiny offset that looks wrong at certain angles.
Basically the distance i want to get is the width of the player, and his center y which is height/2.

Comment: which point does he rotate around? The start of the arrow? And what would be the the rotation for the second image?

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that the first code segment uses `this.width` but the second uses `this.width/2`.  Seems like you have a different reference point.

Comment: Also, it would be useful to see exactly how it behaves for given angles and positions.

Comment: While I realize that the second code snippet is meant to offset the bullet in a way that it's centered around the spawn point, you also have to calculate this offset using trigonometry. As long as there is nothing wrong with the rotation variable, the first calculation seems to be correct.

Comment: ok how would i calculate the offset of the bullet to be centered according to the rotation? Ill try that and then ill get back to you

Comment: The same way you did with the first calculation: multiply the widths/heights by the cosine/sine of the rotation before you subtract. You would need to pass the rotation to the Bullet class (unless it already knows it)

Comment: Ok bullet offset is done. And keiwan was right, i should take the center of the player and not his drawing point.
`this.bulletSpawn.x = (float)(this.position.x + this.width/2 + this.width * Math.cos(rotation));
        this.bulletSpawn.y = (float)(this.position.y + this.height/2 + this.height/2 * Math.sin(rotation));` Still theres a tiny difference but its better

Comment: Vector2? are you talking about some sublibrary??

Comment: yeah but nvm that. Vector2 is just a var with 2 sub vars. its Vector2(float x, float y). so its vector2.x vector2.y. But nvm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's initial position is `X0, Y0`, rotation is about center point `CX, CY`, and rotation angle is `Theta`. So new position after rotation is:

```
 NX = CX + (X0-CX) * Cos(Theta) - (Y0-CY) * Sin(Theta)
 NY = CY + (X0-CX) * Sin(Theta) + (Y0-CY) * Cos(Theta)
```

This equations describe affine transformation of rotation of arbitrary point about center point, and affine matrix is combination of translation, rotation, and back translation matrices.

About center CX, CY - you wrote

> it rotates related to his x and y origin at his bottom left

About initial point coordinate - for bullet it seems to be

```
X + Width, Y + Height/2
```

Comment: please add some explanation, i dont like to copy paste. When you say initial position, whos initial position? the player? the bulletspawn? if you mean the player you mean his draw point? (meaning his 0,0 on the sprite rectangle). Even more, if you can relate it to the code i posted it would be even better.

Comment: actually the Sprite rotates on the center of the rect, but i dont have this variable it does this from the library. What i have is the origin from which is drawn which is its bottom left coordinate. So what i need now is to calculate the center of the rectangle including its rotation, so i can use that in your CX and CY. I have the sprite left,bottom coorindate in the screen, rotation angle, and i have its width and height

Comment: basically with your solution i need to calculate CX and CY, which i also need help with if you can lend me a hand

Comment: nvm, the center of a rectangle is always the same doesnt matter its rotation. your solution worked. i also removed the offset of the bullets that Keiwan mentioned and now it seems even more accurate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Swift extension:

```
extension CGSize {
    static func offsetFrom(angle:CGFloat, distance:CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        let rad = angle * CGFloat.pi / 180
        return CGSize(width: sin(rad) * distance, height: cos(rad) * distance)
    }
}
```